# Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/core/executor/AppToolkitTaskExecutor

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room, livecycle, android-livedata

I'm currently trying to setup Room with Retrofit2. I would like to insert data from Retrofit2 into Room Database but the insertion doesn't work for me and the app crashed. I have implemented three Components using Room Library : entities, Dao and the Database.

I have as Result this error.

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.a694532.e_controlling, PID: 31841
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/core/executor/AppToolkitTaskExecutor;
                      at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker.refreshVersionsAsync(InvalidationTracker.java:403)
                      at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.endTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:219)
                      at com.example.a694532.e_controlling.data.db.dao.GareDao_Impl.insertGares(GareDao_Impl.java:116)
                      at com.example.a694532.e_controlling.service.repository.TotoRepository$1.onResponse(TotoRepository.java:106)
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.a694532.e_controlling-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                      at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker.refreshVersionsAsync(InvalidationTracker.java:403) 
                      at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.endTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:219) 
                      at com.example.a694532.e_controlling.data.db.dao.GareDao_Impl.insertGares(GareDao_Impl.java:116) 
                      at com.example.a694532.e_controlling.service.repository.TotoRepository$1.onResponse(TotoRepository.java:106) 
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                            ... 13 more
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available`

Repository.class

```
 @Singleton
public class TotoRepository {

    //Converters
    private GareDtoConverter mGareConverter = new GareDtoConverter();
    private TrainDuJourDtoConverter mTrainDuJourConverter = new TrainDuJourDtoConverter();

    private TotoService totoService;
    private Executor executor;
    private GareDao gareDao;
    private TrainDao trainDao;
    private TronconDao tronconDao;
    GareEtTrainDuJour mGareEtTrain=new GareEtTrainDuJour();

    MyDatabase database;

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

    public TotoRepository (Application application) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .create();
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(EndPoint.TICKET)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        totoService = retrofit.create(TotoService.class);
        database = MyDatabase.getInstance(application);
        gareDao=database.garesDao();
        trainDao=database.trainDao();
        tronconDao=database.tronconDao();


    }

    /*
    @Inject
    public TotoRepository(TotoService totoService, GareDao gareDao,TrainDao trainDao,TronconDao tronconDao, Executor executor) {
        this.totoService=totoService;
        this.gareDao=gareDao;
        this.trainDao=trainDao;
        this.tronconDao=tronconDao;
        this.executor = executor;
    }*/


public GareEtTrainDuJour getGareEtTrainDuJour() {
    refreshGareEtTrainDuJour();
    // return a LiveData directly from the database.
    Log.d("loadFromDb","Recuperation des gares et trains du jours depuis la BD");

     mGareEtTrain.setGareList(gareDao.getGares());
     mGareEtTrain.setTrainList(trainDao.getTrains());
     mGareEtTrain.setTronconList(tronconDao.getTroncons());

     return mGareEtTrain;

}




    public void refreshGareEtTrainDuJour(){

        totoService.garesEtTrainsDuJour().enqueue(new Callback<GaresEtTrainsDuJourDTO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GaresEtTrainsDuJourDTO> call, Response<GaresEtTrainsDuJourDTO> response) {

                gareDao.insertGares(mGareConverter.toModelList(response.body().getGares()));
                Map<String, Gare> listNameGare = mGareConverter.myListMapper(mGareConverter.toModelList(response.body().getGares()));
                trainDao.insertOrReplaceTrains(mTrainDuJourConverter.toTrainModelList(response.body().getTrains(),listNameGare));
                Log.d("RBRBRBRBRB",mTrainDuJourConverter.toTrainModelList(response.body().getTrains(),listNameGare).toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GaresEtTrainsDuJourDTO> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("RBRBRBRBRBFFFF",t.getCause().toString());
                Log.d("RBRBRBRBRBFFFF",t.toString());
                t.printStackTrace();



            }
        });
    }

}
```

ViewModel.class

```
public class TotoViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private GareEtTrainDuJour mGareEtTrain;
private TotoRepository totoRepo;

@Inject
public TotoViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    totoRepo=new TotoRepository(application);
}

public void init() {
    mGareEtTrain=totoRepo.getGareEtTrainDuJour();
}



public GareEtTrainDuJour getGaresTrain() {
    return this.mGareEtTrain;
}
```

}

Comment: Got any solution? facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just set gradle dependencies to latest and **it works.**

**build.gradle(project-level)**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle(app-level)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
}
```